# lib内のmoduleからmodの利用方法

Tags: rust

下記の様な構成でファイルを作成し

```
src/lib.rs
src/myerror.rs
src/mydata.rs
```

mydataでmyerrorを利用したいと考えたのですが、下記の様なエラーが出ます。
`` error[E0583]: file not found for module `myerror` ``

mydataからmyerrorをmodするにはどの様にすれば良いですか？
myerrorをlib内で共通のエラー処理として使用したいと考えています。

src/mydata.rs

```
mod myerror;

pub struct MyData{}

impl MyData{
    pub fn ok_func(&self) -> Result<(),()>{
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn err_fnuc(&self)->Result<(),myerror::Error>{
        Err(myerror::err())
    }
}
```

src/myerror.rs

```
extern crate failure;
use failure::Error as OtherError;

pub type Error = OtherError;

pub fn err() -> Error{
    failure::format_err!("error")
}
```

src/lib.rs

```
mod mydata;
use mydata::MyData;

pub fn  test1() {
    let mydata = MyData{};
    let ret = mydata.err_fnuc();
    println!("{:?}", ret);

}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    test1();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod` を宣言できるのは親モジュールだけになります。ここでは `lib.rs` が親(ルート)にあたり、mydataとmyerrorは兄弟になっています。
なので `lib` 内で `mod` 宣言をすれば使えるかと思います。
また、Rust 2018では`extern crate`が不要になりました。それらを踏まえると以下のように書けます。

mydata.rs

```rust
use crate::myerror;

pub struct MyData {}

impl MyData {
    pub fn ok_func(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn err_fnuc(&self) -> Result<(), myerror::Error> {
        Err(myerror::err())
    }
}
```

myerror.rs

```rust
use failure::Error as OtherError;

pub type Error = OtherError;

pub fn err() -> Error {
    failure::format_err!("error")
}
```

lib.rs

```rust
mod mydata;
mod myerror;
use mydata::MyData;

pub fn test1() {
    let mydata = MyData {};
    let ret = mydata.err_fnuc();
    println!("{:?}", ret);
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    test1();
}
```

手前味噌ですが昔解説を書いたのでよかったら参考にして下さい。
https://keens.github.io/blog/2018/12/08/rustnomoju_runotsukaikata_2018_editionhan/